# Error in uploading excel file to database

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, excel

I am working on a webform which has a file upload and a button and a gridview. user can upload excel file to database and also see preview in gridview .It is workin fine.
my code is

```
string filename = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.FileName);
    FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Publisher/ExcelFiles/") + filename);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    string path = @"~/Publisher/ExcelFiles/" + filename;
    OleDbConnection myCon = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;");
    OleDbCommand myComm = new OleDbCommand("select * from [GIRLS$] ", myCon);
    OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(myComm);
    da.Fill(ds);
    GridView1.DataSource = ds;
    GridView1.DataBind();
```

but my problem is path of excel file it gives me an error at da.Fill(ds);

> 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\DevServer\10.0\~\Publisher\ExcelFiles\glist.xls' is not a valid path.  Make sure that the path name is spelled correctly and that you are connected to the server on which the file resides.
>   excel file resides in my website directory. This error don't come if I changed the path to

```
string path= @"D:\Vikas Rana\New folder (4)\glist.xls";
```

any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
string filename = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.FileName);

DataSet ds = new DataSet();
string path = Server.MapPath("~/Publisher/ExcelFiles/" + filename);
        FileUpload1.SaveAs(path);
OleDbConnection myCon = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;
DataSource=" + path + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;");
OleDbCommand myComm = new OleDbCommand("select * from [GIRLS$] ", myCon);
OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(myComm);
da.Fill(ds);
GridView1.DataSource = ds;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

if you upload .xls file use this

```
 Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=path(which you prefer);Extended Properties="Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;"
```

if you upload .xlsx file use this

```
 Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=path(which you prefer);Extended Properties="Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;"
```

I mean

```
 OleDbConnection myCon = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;
  DataSource=" + path + ";Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;");
```

Comment: this error related to provider you gave.which file you choosen .xls file or any other(.xlsx file)

Comment: if you use .xls file use this

Comment: Oh at last i solve it by changing sheet name and using my same code